# python pandas merge_asof groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a merged dataframe as follows:

```
>>> merged_df.dtypes
Jurisdiction                  object
AdjustedVolume               float64
EffectiveStartDate    datetime64[ns]
VintageYear                    int64
ProductType                   object
Rate                         float32
Obligation                   float32
Demand                       float64
Cost                         float64
dtype: object
```

The below groupby statement returns the correct AdjustedVolume values by Jurisdiction/Year:

```
>>> merged_df.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'VintageYear'])['AdjustedVolume'].sum()
```

When including ProductType:

```
>>> merged_df.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'VintageYear','ProductType'])['AdjustedVolume'].sum()
```

AdjustedVolume by Year is correct if the Jurisdiction contains only one ProductType, but for any Jurisdiction with two or more ProductTypes, the AdjustedVolumes are getting split up such that they sum to the correct value. I was expecting each row to have the total AdjustedVolume, and am unclear on why it's being split up.

example:

```
>>> merged_df.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'VintageYear'])['AdjustedVolume'].sum()
Jurisdiction  VintageYear  AdjustedVolume
CA            2017         3.529964e+05


>>> merged_df.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'VintageYear','ProductType'])['AdjustedVolume'].sum()
Jurisdiction  VintageYear  ProductType  AdjustedVolume
CA            2017         Bucket1      7.584832e+04
CA            2017         Bucket2      1.308454e+05
CA            2017         Bucket3      1.463026e+05
```

I suspect the merge_asof is being done incorrectly:

```
>>> df1.dtypes
Jurisdiction                  object
ProductType                   object
VintageYear                    int64
EffectiveStartDate    datetime64[ns]
Rate                         float32
Obligation                   float32
dtype: object
>>> df2.dtypes
Jurisdiction                  object
AdjustedVolume               float64
EffectiveStartDate    datetime64[ns]
VintageYear                    int64
dtype: object
```

Because df2 has no ProductType field, the below merge is breaking up the total volume into whatever ProductTypes are under each Jurisdiction. Can I modify the below merge so each ProductType has the total AdjustedVolume?

```
merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='EffectiveStartDate', by=['Jurisdiction','VintageYear'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use both versions of the group by and merge the two tables.
The first table is a group by with the ProductType, which would break out your AdjustedVolume by ProductType.

```
df = df.groupby(['Jurisdiction','VintageYear','ProductType']).agg({'AdjustedVolume':'sum'}).reset_index(drop = False)
```

Then create another table without including the ProductType (This is where the total amount will come from).

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Jurisdiction','VintageYear']).agg({'AdjustedVolume':'sum'}).reset_index(drop = False)
```

Now create an ID column, in both tables, in order for the merge to work correctly.

```
df['ID'] = df['Jurisdiction'].astype(str)+'_' +df['VintageYear'].astype(str)
df1['ID'] = df1['Jurisdiction'].astype(str)+'_'+ df1['VintageYear'].astype(str)
```

Now merge on IDs to get the total adjusted volumne.

```
df = pd.merge(df, df1, left_on = ['ID'], right_on = ['ID'], how = 'inner')
```

Last step is to clean up your columns.

```
df = df.rename(columns = {'AdjustedVolume_x':'AdjustedVolume',
                          'AdjustedVolume_y':'TotalAdjustedVolume',
                          'Jurisdiction_x':'Jurisdiction',
                          'VintageYear_x':'VintageYear'})
del df['Jurisdiction_y']
del df['VintageYear_y']
```

Your output will look like:

[image]

Comment: Couple of slight, style adjustments: the `drop= False` arg is default for `reset_index()` so is redundant and you can delete columns with [`.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Consider also [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to retrieve grouping aggregate inline with other records, akin to the subquery aggregate in SQL.

```
grpdf = merged_df.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'VintageYear','ProductType'])['AdjustedVolume']\
                 .sum().reset_index()

grpdf['TotalAdjVolume'] = merged_df.groupby(['Jurisdiction', 'ProductType'])['AdjustedVolume']\
                                   .transform('sum')
```